# Wordpress loop counter issue

Tags: php, wordpress, loops

I have this piece of code thats pulling through a custom post type clients...

```
<div class="wrap" style="padding-top: 0 !important;">

    <?php
        $args = array( 
          'post_type' => 'short_courses',
          // 'orderby' => 'none',
          'course_type' => 'digital-marketing'
        );
        $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
    ?>

    <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>


        <div class="one-third course-item">
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">

                <p><img src="<?php the_field('listing_thumbnail'); ?>"></p>
                <h4><?php the_title(); ?></h4> 
                <p style="color: #f08464;"><?php the_field('date_for_thumbnail_listing'); ?></p>  
                <p><?php the_field('price'); ?></p>
                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="sc-box-button" style="background-color: #f08464; margin-bottom: 40px;">MORE INFO</a>

            </a>
        </div>

    <?php $products_count = $the_query->current_post + 1; ?>
    <?php if ( $products_count % 4 == 0): ?>

    <?php endif; ?>


    <?php endwhile; wp_reset_postdata(); endif; ?>

</div>
```

All working great, but with the bit at the bottom:

```
<?php $products_count = $the_query->current_post + 1; ?>
<?php if ( $products_count % 4 == 0): ?>
```

I'm trying to get the items to flow onto the next line after 4 items... currently it's doing it after 3 items...

Apologies if it's something simple I'm missing!!!

***** UPDATE FIXED ******

Sorry - I had achieved this effect with CSS, apologies but it was just down to me changing the CSS element to:

```
@media (min-width: 576px) {
  .card-columns {
    column-count: 4; }
}
```

Comment: remove +1 from this line `<?php $products_count = $the_query->current_post + 1; ?>` and check

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***2 ways to do that:-***

1.Either Add counter befor loop and then increment it and check(***standered+best way***)

```
$products_count = 0;
<?php if ( have_posts() ) :
  //rest code as it is
<?php $products_count++; ?>
<?php if ( $products_count % 4 == 0): ?> //rest code as it is
```

2.Or Remove +1 from `<?php $products_count = $the_query->current_post; ?>`

Comment: Sorry - I had achieved this effect with CSS, apologies but it was just down to me changing the CSS element to: 

@media (min-width: 576px) {
  .card-columns {
    column-count: 4; }
}

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend doing this before the while:

```
$products_count = 0;
```

And this for counting:

```
$products_count++;
if ( $products_count % 4 == 0): ...
```

Comment: Sorry - I had achieved this effect with CSS, apologies but it was just down to me changing the CSS element to: 

@media (min-width: 576px) {
  .card-columns {
    column-count: 4; }
}

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php $products_count = $the_query->current_post; ?>
```

Remove only +1 from the above code.

Comment: Sorry - I had achieved this effect with CSS, apologies but it was just down to me changing the CSS element to: 

@media (min-width: 576px) {
  .card-columns {
    column-count: 4; }
}